# Nested foreach using by linq in asp.net mvc

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach, nested

```
foreach (var item in MyDatas)
{
List<int> MyIntegerIdValues= item.StringIdValues.Split(',').Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToList();
foreach (var Id in MyIntegerIdValues)
{
List<string> UserNameList= context.KULLANICILAR.Where(s => s.UserId== Id ).Select(s => s.UserName).ToList();
}
}
```

I have 3 Id Data Values however , 
UserNameList always has 1 count data.I can not keep all datas in list.How can i keep my all datas in UserNameList ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if I understand... you have a DB lookup table with user info and you want all the user names from a list of all the user ids? You dont need a foreach loop at all unless you are doing more processing.  I suspect even that could be done in the select.  Try this linq statement...

```
List<string> UserNameList = context.KULLANICILAR.Where(x=> MyIntegerIdValues.Contains(x.UserId)).Select(x=>x.UserName).ToList();
```

As a full LinqPad sample check out the below code.  The output is below also...

```
public class KULLANICILARItem {
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    // Fake DB Context
    List<KULLANICILARItem> KULLANICILAR = new List<KULLANICILARItem>() {
        new KULLANICILARItem() {
            UserId = 1,
            UserName = "Bob"
        },
        new KULLANICILARItem() {
            UserId = 2,
            UserName = "Jane"
        },
        new KULLANICILARItem() {
            UserId = 3,
            UserName = "Soner"
        },
    };

    // Fake ID List
    List<int> MyIntegerIdValues = new List<int>() {
        1, 2, 3
    };

    List<string> UserNameList = KULLANICILAR.Where(x=> MyIntegerIdValues.Contains(x.UserId)).Select(x=>x.UserName).ToList();

    UserNameList.Dump();
}


Output:
Bob
Jane
Soner
```

To loop over a list of lists, you need only move the string list definition outside of the foreach loop and then add range.

```
public class KULLANICILARItem {
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    // Fake DB Context
    List<KULLANICILARItem> KULLANICILAR = new List<KULLANICILARItem>() {
        new KULLANICILARItem() {
            UserId = 1,
            UserName = "Bob"
        },
        new KULLANICILARItem() {
            UserId = 2,
            UserName = "Jane"
        },
        new KULLANICILARItem() {
            UserId = 3,
            UserName = "Soner"
        },
        new KULLANICILARItem() {
            UserId = 4,
            UserName = "Jim"
        }
    };

    List<string> UserNameList = new List<string>();

    foreach(var StringIdValues in new string[] { "1,2", "3,4"} )
    {
        List<int> MyIntegerIdValues = StringIdValues.Split(',').Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToList();
        UserNameList.AddRange(KULLANICILAR.Where(x=> MyIntegerIdValues.Contains(x.UserId)).Select(x=>x.UserName).ToList());
    }

    UserNameList.Dump();
}
```

Comment: it works only for first list i have many lists i need foreach do you have any idea ?

Comment: MyIntegerIdValues has datas.
1. data :  1, 2, 3
2. data : 6,7,8
Your code works only for 1. data not second one. That is why i need foreach till datas finish

Comment: I think this could be done in far less code, but to stick to your requirements and example I have updated my answer.  You need to move the list outside of the foreach loop and add the names to the list using AddRange.